# Detect text-overflow has worked and add tooltip containing full text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple span containing an email address.

```
<span id="email">dave@davemail.dave</span>
```

In my CSS, the span is set to a fixed width with ellipsis overflow.

```
#email {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This works fine. However, I'd like to detect that it's worked somehow and display the full text in the span's `title` attribute.

How can I do this? Pure CSS would be perfect, but if that's not possible then jQuery is the next best thing.

Comment: Can you not just put it in the title anyway, people that can already see it won't be hovering to look for it

Comment: You can't modify DOM with CSS to add the `title` attribute, so it'll have to be Javascript/jQuery. [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) is amazing for this

Comment: @SmokeyPHP, it's not for this one box, it's for a bunch of them on a page. Sorry, adding the title to every span on the page containing it's content seems overkill, just to cater for the 1% of our users that have long email addresses or quadruple-barrelled surnames! :P

Comment: @RGraham, thought that'd be the case. Was wondering if there was some DOM magic like the `:after { content: 'blah' }`. dotdotdot don't seem to have anything about tooltips on their site. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ConnellWatkins The `callback` method allows you to test if an ellipsis was added, you can then just set the `title` attribute as required

Comment: Aha! Thank you. However, I've already gone with @insertusernamehere's solution because it's much more lightweight.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't detect an overflow with CSS. But using JavaScript it's simply this:

**JavaScript**

```
var e = document.getElementById('email');

if (e.scrollWidth > e.clientWidth) {
    alert("Overflow");
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/nsngdp7b/)

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Dave will be happy ;) Can I ask why you changed from `offsetWidth` to `clientWidth`? Both seemed to work fine (I'm using Chrome)

Comment: The thing with `offsetWidth` is, that it also includes borders. Take a look at this extreme [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdKvn) where it will fail.

Comment: Why the convoluted expression? This is equivalent: `if (e.scrollWidth > e.clientWidth)`.

Comment: @DanielLidström Beats me. Good point. I've updated the answer with the simpler expression. I think I took it from a project of mine, where some other things were taken into the equation and I didn't simplify it enough for this answer.