# show Tooltip only when the ellipsis is active

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

HTML:

```html
<td mat-cell [attr.id]="hospital.organizational_id + '_hospitalname'" 
    *matCellDef="let hospital">
    <div id="hospital_name" class="truncate" 
        [matTooltip]="hospital.organization_name.length > 32 ? 
        hospital.organization_name: '' ">
        {{hospital.organization_name}}
    </div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```css
.truncate {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block !important;
}
```

I want a tool-tip to be displayed dynamically purely depending on the ellipsis.But the problem is tool-tip displayed but it is also getting displayed for the data which doesn't have ellipsis.I'm using angular-material

I have written some CSS after referring some sites

The expected behaviour is should get tool-tip only for the data which has ellipsis otherwise it should be hidden and u can see I'm using angular material.

I have seen some solutions with jquery and it doesn't work for me.
Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Overflow of an element can be detected in JavaScript with this helper, using Angular `ElementRef` and a formula from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19156627/8634147):

```js
function isTextTruncated(element: ElementRef): boolean {
  const e = element.nativeElement;
  return e.scrollWidth > e.clientWidth;
}
```

Then, in your component, use it referencing the element with a "`@ViewChild`" property:

```js
  @ViewChild('hospitalName') hospitalNameElement: ElementRef;

  isHospitalNameTruncated(): boolean {
    return isTextTruncated(this.hospitalNameElement);
  }
```

Finally, in the template, add the identifier `#hospitalName` and call `isHospitalNameTruncated()` to customize the tooltip text:

```html
<td mat-cell [attr.id]="hospital.organizational_id + '_hospitalname'"
    *matCellDef="let hospital">
  <div id="hospital_name" #hospitalName class="truncate"
       [matTooltip]="isHospitalNameTruncated() ? hospital.organization_name : null ">
    {{hospital.organization_name}}
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 17):

Based on the Romain Deneau answer I created a small directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[matTooltip][appShowIfTruncated]'
})
export class ShowIfTruncatedDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private matTooltip: MatTooltip,
    private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
  ) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    // Wait for DOM update
    setTimeout(() => {
      const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
      this.matTooltip.disabled = element.scrollWidth <= element.clientWidth;
    });
  }
}
```

You can use it a little bit easier

```
<td mat-cell [attr.id]="hospital.organizational_id + '_hospitalname'" *matCellDef="let hospital">
  <div id="hospital_name" class="truncate" [matTooltip]="hospital.organization_name" appShowIfTruncated>
    {{hospital.organization_name}}
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 15):

Another improvement; Egor's answers is beautiful but unfortunately `ngOnInit` might not be enough. Examples:

- When the element surrounding `[matTooltip]` is resizeable
- When the text itself can be changed dynamically
- When CSS selectors change the element padding/font-weight/font-size etc. and as a result truncates the text after initiation

Therefor the result is to bind to `mouseenter` (At that point, `setTimeout` becomes redundant):

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTooltip } from '@angular/material';

@Directive({
  selector: '[matTooltip][showIfTruncated]'
})
export class ShowIfTruncatedDirective {
  
  constructor(
    private matTooltip: MatTooltip,
    private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
  ) {}

  @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event'])
  setTooltipState(): void {
      const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
      this.matTooltip.disabled = element.scrollWidth <= element.clientWidth;
  }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using the mouseenter event listener because it will attach that event to all elements using your directive. I know this could be a tradeoff by reusing the functionality and avoiding extra event listeners but improving memory and cpu usage is always a must.

Comment: @mmcorrelo it will not attach to all elements. It will only attach to the elements holding both `matTooltip` and `showIfTruncated` attributes. Having few elements with mouseenter event listener is definitely not something I'd worry about.

Comment: Thank you for both your contributions! This is what I am using now.

Answer (score 3):

The approch of mmcorrelo is not reusable but works well for element inside bootstap dropdown. In my opinion we should distinguish `matTooltip` and `matTooltipDisabled`:

```html
<td mat-cell [attr.id]="hospital.organizational_id + '_hospitalname'"
    *matCellDef="let hospital">
  <div id="hospital_name" #el class="truncate"
       [matTooltip]="hospital.organization_name"
       [matTooltipDisabled]="el.scrollWidth < el.clientWidth">
    {{hospital.organization_name}}
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

istead of

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
// Wait for DOM update
  setTimeout(() => {
    const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    this.matTooltip.disabled = element.scrollWidth <= element.clientWidth;
  });
}
```

use

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  this.matTooltip.disabled = element.scrollWidth <= element.clientWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reusing the Romain Deneau answer I would simplify the code to something like this

```
<td mat-cell [attr.id]="hospital.organizational_id + '_hospitalname'"
    *matCellDef="let hospital">
  <div id="hospital_name" #el class="truncate"
       [matTooltip]="(el.scrollWidth > el.clientWidth) ? hospital.organization_name : ''">
    {{hospital.organization_name}}
  </div>
</td>
```